# What does this speaker mean by "Если бы у человека было такое свойство..."

Tags: перевод, одним-словом

**Video:** http://youtu.be/emWWReNhnPw?t=1h28m25s

*Transcript:*
Если бы у человека было такое свойство, как до лени чего-нибудь, я бы постирал бы себе в башке много чего о том, о чем не хочу вспоминать

He's reflecting on his life, and I think talking about some things he'd rather not remember. What does he say about laziness? How would you put it in English? My Russian is only good enough at present to recognise key words :-/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More correct phrase in this video fragment:

*Если бы у человека было такое свойство, как **УДАЛЕНИЕ** чего-нибудь, я бы постирал у себя в башке много чего того, о чем не хочу вспоминать.*

So, this teenager says about removing memories.